# Can not grant permission from remote access

Tags: mysql

I have a root account and It is able to connect to mysql server from any hosting. 
It's working as well if I run command from mysql server ( local access)

```
grant all on *.* to testacc@'%';
```

But It doesn't work if I connect Mysql from different servers ( remote access) 
It throws an error such as :

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Please share to me the problem and solution!

Thanks all.

Comment: You're giving permissions to the user "testacc" then connecting as "root"?

Comment: Yes. I want to set permission for user 'testacc' by connecting with root account. But the problem is solved now. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is may be your port is not opened for mysql transaction,
I've just tried to open the port 3306 following these steps:

1. Open Control Panel from the Start menu.
2. Select Windows Firewall.
3. Select Advanced settings in the left column of the Windows Firewall window.
4. Select Inbound Rules in the left column of the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security window.
5. Select New Rule in the right column.
6. Select Port in the New Inbound Rule Wizard and then click Next.
7. Select which protocol this rule will apply to (TCP or UDP), select Specific local ports, type a port number (80), port numbers (80,81), or a range of port numbers (5000-5010) and then click Next.
8. Select Allow the connection and then click Next.
9. Select when this rule applies (check all of them for the port to always stay open) and then click Next.
10. Give this rule a name and then click Finish to add the new rule.